# 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: php, apache

Tenho a seguinte VirutalHost Configurada em meu servidor

```
Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin application
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\application\public"
    ServerName localhost application.com.br
    ErrorLog "logs/application.log"
    CustomLog "logs/application.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Quando eu acesso minha aplicação de localhost ou na rede funciona corretamente mas quando eu acesso via dominio `application.com.br` o seguinte erro é apresentado

```
403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server
```

Comment: Aqui http://application.com.br/ abre uma escola de inglês. (é pra ser uma piada, antes que algum desavisado fale sério isso) :)

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada aqui e parece ser a configuração do seu apache. Dê uma olhada [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

Answer (score 2):

O correto seria:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\application\public"
    ServerName application.com.br
    ErrorLog "logs/application.log"
    CustomLog "logs/application.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Você adicionou um espaço no ServerName, não pode isso, nos meus teste sempre apresentava um erro quando realizava esse tipo de coisa.

Outra coisa e editar seu arquivos de hosts para aporntar o endereço application.com.br para seu IP local, do contrário jamais acessará a aplicação de teste.

leia o [leia o seguinte artigo](http://www.thiagocolares.com.br/?p=439) para esclarecer todas as dúvidas sobre o tema.